# Can I carry a PC in a flight?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airlines, airport-security, packing

I was wondering if I can bring my all in one lenovo pc. It's exactly or similar to this https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lenovo-C345-20-inch-All-Desktop/dp/B00DPJZQ98 . I was wondering if it'll be to big or exceed the limit and won't go through.[image]

Comment: What research have you done so far? Eg the TSA website might help? https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/desktop-computers

Comment: Where are you travelling from? Is this in hold luggage or hand luggage?

Comment: I'm traveling from Columbia SC, to Houston TX. I will either be riding American Airlines or Delta.

Comment: You need to measure the size of the box you'll be putting it in, and then compare it to the limits imposed by your airline.

Comment: Put it back in its original box and take it as checked luggage. You're very likely to end up with a broken screen if you carry this on, if they even allow you to at all.

Comment: I already carried a xbox 360 and I did not have issue.

Answer (score 2):

Each airline has different rules. For most airlines that would be too big/heavy for carry on but ok as checked luggage, provided it's properly boxed up.

Comment: If it will fit in carry on, definitely go that way. If it's too big and you must put it in checked luggage, your best bet is the original box it came in with the original, form-fitting packaging. If you don't have that, think _very_ seriously about how you pack it - lots of bubble wrap, peanuts, etc; pack the box **full** so it can't shift or be crushed by weight on top of it. **INSURE** it when you check it claiming full replacement value. Just like you'd do if you were shipping UPS/FedEx/etc.